# Report Builder- Label parameter

Tags: sql, report

I have this problem: I need to assign one label with multiple values.
I have this query:

```
CASE WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag = 1 THEN 'Non-inventoried'

WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag =2 THEN 'Inventoried'

--WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag =3 THEN 'Inventoried from PC'

--WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag = 4 THEN 'Inventoried with chnages'

--WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag = 5 THEN 'Inventoried with chnages'

--WHEN AssetsInventoryHistory.inv_flag = 6 THEN 'Inventoried with chnages'
```

[Available values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqBTU.png)

I need 2 'labels' .One for 1 - NON Inventoried (it's ok) and a second label for all the others (2,3,4,5,6) cause i don't care how there are inventoried.I need only to see all non-inventoried and all the inventoried assetes.

I've tried:

```
="Join(Parameters!param.Value,",") , =Join(Parameters!param.Label,",")
and =Split(Parameters!param.Value,",")
```

...but doesn't work. (i have selected multi value option)

Any idea? Thank you

I've tried split and join.

Comment: Proper code formatting would make this easier to read. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. (Or simply highlight code and click `{}`.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, just leave the parameters the way they are and add the logic to your query. Something like this:

```sql
select *
from AssetsInventoryHistory
where ((Parameters!param.Value = 1 and inv_flag = 1)
    or (Parameters!param.Value = 2 and inv_flag in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Of course, you could do weird shit like have the parameter values be `;1;` and `;2;3;4;5;6;` and do the query condition like this:

```sql
where Parameters!param.Value like '%;' + inv_flag + ';%'
```

The advantages being that you only need to change the parameter value when you eventually introduce inv_flag `7`, and it's less verbose, obviously. But you may feel disgusted by the string manipulation and propensity to weird bugs if you forget a `;` or put a space somewhere or something.